# Kafka Leader not available after configuring ACL

Tags: apache-kafka

I had configured **SSL** and **SASL** security and tried to produce data to Kafka topic and working fine without issues.

But after configuring **Authorizer**, I am getting the below error even though Authorization is allowed

> [Producer clientId=console-producer] Error while fetching metadata
>   with correlation id 43 : {test_1=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
>   (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

Below is the topic description

```
./kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181 --describe --topic test_1
Topic:test_1    PartitionCount:1    ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:
    Topic: test_1   Partition: 0    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "configuring Authorizer"? What did you do?

Comment: Did you made sure that your Kafka brokers have enough rights to communicate with each other? For example by setting them as the `super.users`?

Comment: After setting up SSL and SASL, we need to give authorization to Topics such as Read / Write operation. I had added super.users also

Comment: Likely duplicate; please have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52209029/1545425