# Fail sending data to kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm getting the following text while trying to send data via kafka producer console to my google cloud kafka:

> Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 12 :
>   {project=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}

This error is repeating. port `9092` and `2181` are open

`curl -vv`  is successful to both

**my server.properties:**

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092 

advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://external-ip:9092
```

Comment: my server.properties:
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://external-ip:9092

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. could you add more details like what version of kafka you are using.. and how you are producing the message?  Also, try looking at the similar kind of problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39718975/apache-kafka-leader-not-available